# How to view the revision history graph of an SVN repository

Tags: svn

I'm working on a project and making some changes hat may be potentially unstable, so I've created a branch. Now I want to find out how many commits have been made on HEAD since I branched out.

How do I do that? I'm thinking in terms of how git's network graph viewer works.. If that's not the way SVN works (or thinks) please correct me.

Thanks :)

PS: I'm not much experienced with SVN. I've used some amount of git though.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand the question correctly. Head is one folder, and branch is another. Look for logs and/or revision graph on head folder. Revision graph is viewable in TortoiseSVN. I don't know of other tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you: [svn-graph-branches](https://code.google.com/p/svn-graph-branches/)

It graphically visualizes how your revision tree is build-up. Have not tested it yet, but will in 5 minutes :-)